# TLS session resumption on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, ssl

We have C++ code that uses TCP/IP to communicate between a client and server and use TLS 1.2 for encryption between the two.  I'd like to implement TLS session resumption as it would speed up reconnections, which will be very often in our software.  I've scoured SO and lots of other places and come up with very little for definitive answers.  The closest I've found is this: https://forums.iis.net/t/1239418.aspx?How+to+enable+TLS+session+resumption+or+Optimize+TLS+handshake+on+Windows+2016+

*The instructions from that site are reproduced here:*

To enable TLS session tickets on win2k12 r2 and win2k16, you need to follow these steps:

1. Create a key (DWORD) in registry with value 1 HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\EnableSslSessionTicket
2. Create a new TLS session ticket key through this powershell command: New-TlsSessionTicketKey -Password -Path "C:\KeyConfig\TlsSessionTicketKey.config" -ServiceAccountName "System" https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/tls/new-tlssessionticketkey
3. Enable TLS session ticket key through this powershell command: Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey -Password -Path "C:\KeyConfig\TlsSessionTicketKey.config" -ServiceAccountName "System"https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/tls/enable-tlssessionticketkey
4. Reboot the server to enable TLS session ticket generation. Reboot is required for the registry entry to take effect.

But I have some issues with it.  I could do it in PowerShell, but I'd prefer to do it in C++ code.  We don't use HTTP, only TCP/IP.  And the service account you specify in Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey may be a user account and not one of the well-defined system accounts.

It can't be this hard, can it?  It's not on by default, is it?  I'm looking at a Wireshark capture and it doesn't look like it's on.  In my Client Hello packets I see: session_ticket len=0, extended_master_secret len=0, renegotiation_info len=1.  In my Server Hello messages I don't see any session ticket.  I see: extended_master_secret len=0, renegotiation_info len=1.

Answer (score 1):

After opening a support ticket with Microsoft, they did finally provide the means to do this. It's still not great, but it works. Not great because we have to do some in a Powershell script (rather do it in code) and the service account cannot be a normal user account.

- You must pass in `ASC_REQ_SESSION_TICKET` (an undocumented option) into
  the `AcceptSecurityContext` call on the server side. This will allow
  the server to generate a ticket
- Do steps 2, 3, and 4 above to create a session ticket then enable it in the Powershell script
- Make sure you only create a single credential on the client side.
- The service account must be one of these: System, LocalService, NetworkService, or SID of virtual accounts.  We used NetworkService